# PowerBook G4 won't connect to Airport with WEP password

Tags: airport

I'm helping at a friend's house. She has a Airport Extreme setup with a WEP (yes, I really do mean WEP) password.  Her iMac running 10.5.8 connects to the network just fine.  I'm typing this question on that iMac.

However when I try connecting to the same network with her PowerBook G4, sitting in the same room as the Airport Extreme, the PowerBook won't connect.  It asks me for a password but I can't get it to accept the password.  The PowerBook is running 10.4.11.

When I select the network, I get dialog that says:

```
The selected AirPort network requires a password to join.

    Wireless Security: WPA Personal

    Password: ______

[ ] Show password

[ ] Remember password in my keychain

(?)   (Cancel)   (OK)
```

(Pardon my ASCII art.) Anyway, the wireless security setting is a pulldown menu, and I want to pull down that menu and select "WEP" or "Transitional WEP", but I can't. WPA Personal is the only available option.

So, needless to say, if I enter the WEP password, it fails to connect.  What do I do?

Comment: Question still stands, im curious to know the answer. but I switched her network to WPA/WPA2 everywhere, reconnected all devices, and she's ok. So not urgent anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Way back in ye olden days I had the same issue with a iBook, it was never a 100% fix but if you go to Airport -> Join Other Network it'll allow you to pick the security type and enter the SSID for the network, that should trick it into working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Also go into AirPort's Advanced options, in the Networking section of System Preferences, and make sure that it doesn't 'remember' a network with the same name as the one you're trying to join: perhaps your friend changed the security but not the name, so the PB is trying to supply the wrong type of security credentials.